# Let $f, g : I \to \Bbb S^1$, where $f(t) = e^{i\pi t} \ \text{ and } \ g(t) = e^{-i\pi t}.$ Construct a homotopy $F : f \simeq g$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $f, g : I \to \Bbb S^1$, where $$f(t) = e^{i\pi t} \ \text{ and } \ g(t) = e^{-i\pi t}.$$ Construct a homotopy $F : f \simeq g$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are defined using complex numbers I think that in this case $\Bbb S^1$ is embedded in the complex plane. Can we not use the straight line homotopy here? If I let $F: I \times I \to \Bbb S^1$ be the map $$F(t,s) = se^{-i \pi t} + (1-s)e^{i \pi t}$$ then $F(t,0) = e^{i \pi t}$ and $F(t,1) = e^{-i \pi t}$. This is continuous and all of the points should lie on the complex sphere with radius $1$.

Comment: Do you need your homotopy to keep the endpoints of the paths fixed or can they vary?
Also, notice that your map $F$ does not take values in $\mathbb{S}^1$. For each $t \in I$, $f(t)$ is a point in the north hemisphere  of $\mathbb{S}^1$, while $g(t)$ is in the south hemisphere, so your straight line homotopy $F$ passes through the "inside" of the circle.

Comment: You must have $F(t,s) \in \mathbb{S}^1$ for all $s,t$. $F({1 \over 2}, {1 \over 2}) = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think this could be salvaged by composing this homotopy with the map $x/\|x\|$?

Comment: @EdmundoMartins I don't need the homotopy to keep the endpoints fixed in this problem. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Why don't you think about mapping $I \to [-1,1]$ instead and think about why I am suggesting that?

Comment: Hmm. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $H(t,s)=e^{i\pi t(1-2s)}$. Then, $H:I\times I\rightarrow S^1$ is clearly a map (continuous function) into the circle. We also check the boundry conditions: $H(t,0)=e^{i\pi t}=f(t)$ and $H(t,1)=e^{-i\pi t}=g(t)$. So, $f\simeq g$. They are homotopic.

Your homotopy is not into the unit circle. Take $t=\frac{1}{4}$, $s=\frac{1}{2}$, then $F(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is not on the unit circle.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what do you mean by the homotopy being not into the circle? @BobDobbs

Comment: At each "moment" in the homotopy (particular value of $s$), the path $h_s$ defined by $h_s(t) = H(t, s)$ for all $t \in I$ must take values in $\mathbb{S}^1$. Imagine an animation that begins $(s = 0)$ with the path $f = h_0$ parametrizing the upper semicircle, shrinks to the constant path at $z=1$, and expands back to end $(s = 1)$ with the path $g = h_1$ parametrizing the lower semicircle.